# typescript and ng are not recognized

Tags: node.js, npm, angular-cli

I updated node.JS to v14.17.0, and it turned out that it is not compatible with NPM version so based on a solution that I found on Stack Overflow I uninstalled node.js, npm, removed the nom folder  from `C:\Users\<name>\AppData\Roaming` and uninstall angular, and then I reinstall all of them hoping that this would fix the problem unfortunately  it did not `ng` commands are not recognized, the npm folder is empty and no mutter how many times I reinstall angular/CLI I ng is still not recognized
when I check the verions I get this:

```
node -v => v14.17.0
npm -v  => 7.13.0
tsc -v  =>'tsc' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
ng -v   =>'ng' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

here is what I get when I run : `npm install -g @angular/cli`

```
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142

changed 234 packages, and audited 235 packages in 5m

23 packages are looking for funding
  run `npm fund` for details

found 0 vulnerabilities
```

I am really desperate I could not find any solution so I am asking for your help

**UPDATE**
you can check the image [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/K8I23.png) showing the result of the angular/CLI installation

Comment: `npm uninstall @angular/cli && npm i -g @angular/cli`. Try this.

Comment: it did not work same thing

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of running the above 2 commands

Comment: I added a screenshot in the UPDATE part

Comment: Try it on a new cli. If not works, try above step without terminating batch job. If it's still not working, change node to v12